# Asynchronously catching complex Mongoose errors with Chai.throw

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, tdd, chai

`Chai.throw` is used to test against simple Errors against their `message` prop. In simple error cases, this works fine.

```
it.only('Should catch a thrown message', () => {
    function throwSomething() {
      throw new Error('something')
    }

    expect(throwSomething).to.throw('something')
})
```

However, while testing asynchronously against failing Mongoose validations, I see that I am not able to access a nested error message. I originally wanted to use async tests with try+catch, but the `expect` call inside the catch block is not guaranteed to run, in which case the test may pass when it has not in fact errorred.

```
it.only('Errors on save if username is not unique', async () => {
    // setup original user
    const original = new UserModel(testParams)
    await original.save()

    try {

      // try to create a new user with the same username
      const duplicate = new UserModel({
        username: testParams.username,
        email: 'test_other@mail.com',
        password: testParams.password
      })

      // save the user that has a non-unique username
      await duplicate.save()
    } catch (err) {

      // confirm the nested error was as expected
      expect(err.errors.username.message).to.equal(
        'Error, expected `username` to be unique. Value: ' +
        '`' + testParams.username + '`'
      )
    }
})
```

If I were to call `expect(duplicate.save).to.throw('...')` it would not be checking against the error field that I want.

Another option is that instead of asynchronously testing my models, I use Promise callbacks, and call `done()` inside the `.catch()` callback. However I find this method undesirable if I am testing many nested Promise operations.

Is there a way to use `Chai.throw` to catch complex nested errors produced by Mongoose?